# typeof().GetFields doesnt show List<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I am trying to go through my class, but I am unable to list everything.

I have class:

```
public class Order
{
    public string PO_NO { get; set; }
    public string APPROVED_DATE { get; set; }
    public string SPPLR_CONTACT { get; set; } //SPPLR_Mailbox
    public string PO_REMARKS { get; set; }
    public string PO_CREATION_DATE { get; set; }
    public string SPPLR_CD { get; set; }
    public string OWN_CD { get; set; }
    public string LOCATION_CODE { get; set; }
    public string LOCATION_ID { get; set; }
    public string SHIPPING_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string FREIGHT_TERMS { get; set; }
    public string PO_STATUS { get; set; }
    public string CONTACT_PERSON { get; set; }
    public string CONTACT_PERSON_MAIL { get; set; }
    public string CONTACT_PERSON_PHONE { get; set; }

    public string ATTRIBUTE01 { get; set; }
    public string ATTRIBUTE02 { get; set; }
    public string ATTRIBUTE03 { get; set; }
    public string ATTRIBUTE04 { get; set; }
    public string ATTRIBUTE05 { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetails> OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();
}
```

And I am trying to "enumerate" it like that

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Order).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(field.Name + "---" + field.FieldType);
}
```

Getting this output:

```
<PO_NO>k__BackingField---System.String
<APPROVED_DATE>k__BackingField---System.String
<SPPLR_CONTACT>k__BackingField---System.String
<PO_REMARKS>k__BackingField---System.String
<PO_CREATION_DATE>k__BackingField---System.String
<SPPLR_CD>k__BackingField---System.String
<OWN_CD>k__BackingField---System.String
<LOCATION_CODE>k__BackingField---System.String
<LOCATION_ID>k__BackingField---System.String
<SHIPPING_TYPE>k__BackingField---System.String
<FREIGHT_TERMS>k__BackingField---System.String
<PO_STATUS>k__BackingField---System.String
<CONTACT_PERSON>k__BackingField---System.String
<CONTACT_PERSON_MAIL>k__BackingField---System.String
<CONTACT_PERSON_PHONE>k__BackingField---System.String
<ATTRIBUTE01>k__BackingField---System.String
<ATTRIBUTE02>k__BackingField---System.String
<ATTRIBUTE03>k__BackingField---System.String
<ATTRIBUTE04>k__BackingField---System.String
<ATTRIBUTE05>k__BackingField---System.String
```

The List is missing, what is wrong, or what can I do, to get it there listed?

I am trying to make library for myslef, to which I could just hang class and whole xml would get generated, but I would not be able to do structure dynamicaly, since I am not getting that List (child node)

Comment: You have left out the exact code that is responsible for what you see. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @nvoigt What do you mean? The whole code, which is repsonsible for the output is the code block in the middle. (The foreach statement) Nothing more. It is simple console application.

Comment: The fact that you only get the private backing fields in your list tells me that you probably use the wrong `BindingFlags`.

Comment: @thehennyy Yeah, you are right, I did not think that would be cause, because all of the variables are public. But after adding I am getting my desired output BindingFlags.Public
Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thehenny stated, the BindingFlags werent right. I just added BindingFlags.Public

so the code went from:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Order).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );
       foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(field.Name + "---" + field.FieldType);
            }
```

To:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Order).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(field.Name + "---" + field.FieldType);
            }
```